# Where to apply for making a complaint about Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I asked a question couple days ago on UX. Experinced members of here put my question "on hold" status because my question was "too broad". It was okay. I acknowledged it.

[image]
![info box][1]

So I followed the regulations above. First I edited my question to narrow it's scope down. But I did not get any notifications to find out what was next. Then I leaved a comment but again I did not get any notifications. My question was still at "on hold" status.

Well, I might be the person who could not achieve to ask the "true" question even after corrections. The only thing I wanted to know was my question's destiny. If It is still "too broad" according to "experienced members" then close it.

So I gave a feedback to stack exchange team about this issue a couple days ago. Unfortunately, they did not answer back to me.

Dear experienced members,
This was my user experience on UX. My question's status is "on hold" for four days. So, where can I apply about this issue? Can you help me? Or just forget about that..

Comment: Thanks for not putting it "on hold"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By editing your On Hold question it was then automatically added to the 'Re-open' review queue for people to look over and see if it qualified for reopening. However it was not deemed suitable for reopening so was left on hold. (I myself reviewed, this and as a moderator I get binding votes so it didn't get reviewed by anyone else after I cast my vote).

The main issue is that the crux of your question has not changed. The main question part is:

> What I would like to ask you is what type of questions should I ask to build a perfect CRM system.

That is a very broad question. There is no correct answer to this post; it's a discussion topic really. No single answer would be more correct than another.

You need to explain the problem you have, describe the resolution you tried to put in place and why that isn't working and then come to us to say: *"I have {this problem}. I have tried to address it by {doing X} but that hasn't improved the situation because I am still getting {unwanted outcome}, so what can I do to achieve {desired outcome}."*

This isn't a discussion forum - it is a specific Question and Answer site, involving questions that people have and the specific Solutions to that problem. "What type of questions should I ask" isn't a question that has a specific solution.

But in answer to your actual post here - "Where to apply for making a complaint about Stack Exchange?" then that is https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/ if the complain is specific to UX.Stackexchange, or https://meta.stackexchange.com/ if your question is about the general software that powers these sites.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what I want to get as a "new user" of this q&a site. My problem was not about the question. As I said I acknowledged it. My problem was getting no reaction or result for days.

Comment: @latefreak: Usually I leave a comment on posts when I vote against them, but I think that because it was initially put on hold by community votes and not mod ones I missed the opportunity to leave a comment. I should have therefore done so when reviewing it, but for some reason I didn't do that, so my apologies there.

Comment: @latefreak I've added a feature request on the main Meta site that may help to prevent similar issues in the future. [Notify close-voters when the OP adds a comment after the question was closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238128/notify-close-voters-when-the-op-adds-a-comment-after-the-question-was-closed)

Comment: @JonW It's okay. Everything's fine now. Therefore I comprehended the way of asking questions.

Comment: @3nafish thanks for your consideration. The new future would be perfect for us.